# Questions about arrays in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, oop

I have a class called `Product`, which contains a `name`, `price` and `count`.

In another class called `Shop` (including the class `Product`),  I initialize with an empty array. Then a add `product` to this array using the method `push`.

The problem happens to the method `to_s` of in the `Shop` class :

```
def to_s
  string = "Products in the shop:\n"
  @list.each do |list|
    #### how can i get access to the attributes of product like @list.name or something like that ?  I have tried loads of different methods but i cant get access to my attributes. (the array doesnt recognize the product class)
    puts @list.name
  end
```

If I create a `Product` without using `Array`, I can access to the attributes - I guess the problem comes because of the `Array`...

Comment: First show us the class you have created,then ask us the question pointing to the confusions you are having..

Comment: Is the `end` in your code the end of the `each` block or the end of the `def to_s` block?

Comment: Whoever edited it, you may have changed the OP's question. Note my comment above about mismatched `end`s. =)

Answer (score 3):

So first of all, your blocks don't match up.

You want:

```
def to_s
  string = "Products in the shop:\n"
  @list.each do |item|
    string << item.name + "\n"     # not @list.name! @list is an Array. item is an element of your list.
  end
  string # you could also say: return string
end
```

You don't want to use `puts` because that'll send it to the console -- when you're trying to store it in a String called `string`. You want to make sure you return that, too.

You don't have to call your block parameter `item`. You *could* call it `list`, but that would be confusing, because you have another variable called `@list`, and the block parameter is not a list at all -- just an item from the array.

Note that this is not the most efficient way to accomplish this. The preferred way is like so:

```
def to_s
  products_list = @list.map do |item|
    item.name
  end
  "Products in the shop:\n" + products_list.join("\n")
end
```

Comment: You could also write John's suggested alternative as: `def to_s() "Products in the shop:\n" + @list.map(&:name).join("\n") end`

Comment: Doesn't that need a colon after the `def to_s()`? Also, the parens are optional. =)

Comment: If you remove the parens you'll need to insert one `;` after `to_s` and another before `end`.  Both work.

Answer (score 2):

Each element in `@list` is yielded to the `each` block as `list`.

Assuming `@list` is an Enumerable with `Product` objects, you should be able to do `list.name` to get at the name attribute inside the block.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer `map` and `join` over `each` and `<<` (just a preference), and braces (`{}`) over `do end` because I like to imply a return value is important by using braces, and a `do end` block is there for side effects, e.g.

```
def to_s
  "Products in the shop:\n" << @list.map{|item| item.name}.join("\n")
end
```

I also wouldn't use `puts` because `to_s` should return a string, not output a string.